# Why setParameter() is not available for ServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets, parameters

I have read about Servlet's in many tutorials. The Servlet parameters has `getParameter()` method. As the parameter has return type as only `String`. Why the `ServletRequest` do not have `setParameter()` method ?

I have read about that only attributes in Servlet's can be changed, and the parameters can not. Can anyone explain the basic concept why there is no provision for updating the parameter in request with method  like `setParameter()`?

Answer (score 0):

As per [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) documentation, it is mentioned that :

`Defines an object to provide client request information to a servlet.`

That means ServletRequest object is used to transfer client side information to server methods. For ex. text field values from jsp page to servlet's `doGet` or `doPost` method.

Answer (score 0):

ServletRequest Object  is an client request to a Servlet, and ServletResponse object is the response  sent to the client so always you get the required information from the request and you set the information in the response............!

Answer (score 0):

Application developers use `parameter` for getting information from client, where as `attributes` are used by application developer for overall internal management purposes. You can not change (`setParameter()`) the values given to you by clients in parameters; you can simply get those values using `getParameter()`